# Was Mary pregnant when she visited Elizabeth?

Tags: luke

Luke 1:

> 39 In those days Mary arose and went with haste into the hill country, to a town in Judah, 40and she entered the house of Zechariah and greeted Elizabeth. 41And when Elizabeth heard the greeting of Mary, the baby leaped in her womb. And Elizabeth was filled with the Holy Spirit, 42and she exclaimed with a loud cry, “Blessed are you among women, and blessed is the fruit of your womb! 43And why is this granted to me that the mother of my Lord should come to me? 44For behold, when the sound of your greeting came to my ears, the baby in my womb leaped for joy. 45And blessed is she who believed that there would beg a fulfillment of what was spoken to her from the Lord.”

Comment: Possibly pregnant; but we cannot be certain.  The text is not explicit.

Answer (score 1):

> And, behold, thy cousin Elisabeth, she hath also conceived a son in her old age: and this is the sixth month with her, who was called barren. (Luke 1:36)

The sixth month of gestation comprises from the 21st to the 24th lunar week. During this period, the fetus is still wrinkled. However, he is already able to hear, swallow, and have sensations related to taste.

Did John the Baptist tremble because of Mary or because he recognized the tabernacle of the divine logo?

Then John gave this testimony:

> I saw the Spirit come down from heaven as a dove and remain on him. **And I myself did not know him**, but the one who sent me to baptize with water told me, ‘The man on whom you see the Spirit come down and remain is the one who will baptize with the Holy Spirit.’ I have seen and I testify that this is God’s Chosen One. (John 1:32-35)

In Mary's visit to Elizabeth, did the unborn John the Baptist recognize only the tabernacle of the logos and not the fleshly form of Jesus?

During the visit to Elizabeth, Mary expresses:

> For he hath regarded the low estate of his handmaiden: for, **behold, from henceforth** (ἀπὸ τοῦ νῦν) all generations shall call me blessed. (Luke 1:48)

The prayer (ἀπὸ τοῦ νῦν) also occurs in Luke 5:10; 12:52; 22:18 and 22:69.  So here fits a rigorous grammatical analysis in Greek. I will abstain for not mastering the English language.

In Luke 22:69 it is evident that prayer (ἀπὸ τοῦ νῦν) comprises the beginning of a continuous and progressive process. When Jesus quotes: "Father, why hast thou forsaken me", he said "My God, my God, why hast thou forsaken (or forsaken) me" (Psalm 22:1, Matthew 27:46; Mark 15:34) and we know that the contextualization of Psalms 22, mainly in verse 24, demonstrates that this is an exclamatory phrase to remind the Jews and not the Romans that Jesus will obtain victory.

Comment: Was Mary pregnant when she visited Elizabeth?

Comment: So the prayer (ἀπὸ τοῦ νῦν) in Luke 1:48 may begin with her absolute certainty in the fulfillment of the prophecy and not precisely at the onset of pregnancy. We'll have to investigate the circumstances further.

Answer (score 1):

When Gabriel delivered the message to Zechariah, Zechariah was on duty serving as priest before God (Luke 1:8), the duration was 7 days (Exo 29:30). Then Luke 1:23-24 read

> 23 When his time of service was completed, he returned home.
>
> 24 After this his wife Elizabeth became pregnant and for five months remained
> in seclusion. (NIV)

So "After this" was how long? Would it be more than 3 months?

The same angel Gabriel delivered the message to Mary. She hurried to visit Elizabeth and stayed with her for about three months (Luke 1:56)

Though I believe OP should have asked "Was Mary pregnant on the 1st day she came to Elizabeth?" My answer to this question is; as the whole visit last for about 3 months, Mary should have pregnant during this time.

Though the text did not explicitly tell when Mary got pregnant, but all words of God have a time essence to fulfill. Without a reasonable purpose, I can't find a reason why the fulfillment to their pregnancy  need to be deferred from the time of the message given.

Comment: +1 Between 0 and 10, how much weight do you put on your position?

Comment: @TonyChan - not sure what you mean.

Comment: How sure are you about Mary being pregnant on the 1st day she came to Elizabeth?

Comment: @TonyChan - It should happen at the time the angel delivered the message, for I find no reason of deferment. vv24 though has the phrase "After this", but we know the date of pregnancy is calculated from the time of last period, both Elizabeth and Mary would not know when it started, for it was by the spirit, not by the flesh. Another indirect proof may be, Elizabeth was in seclusion for 5 months (vv24), Gabriel visited Mary in the 6th month of Elizabeth's pregnancy (vv26). If these were consecutive events, Elizabeth should be pregnant at time of message delivered. Same applied to Mary.

Comment: 100% probability?